# If I own a C++ base class but don't own or even know about derived classes, can I tell if a given object is an instance of a derived class?

Tags: c++, hierarchy, radix, derived

I can't use dynamic_cast because I don't know the names of the derived classes. Similarly for std::is_base_of.

Comment: Is the base class pure virtual? Then the answer is yes, for what it's worth.

Comment: Normally, if you care whether an object is actually a derived type or the base type then you probably made a mistake in how you used inheritance.

Comment: the question is unclear. You dont need to know the name of a type to query properties of the type. Once you have an object: `using type_of_the_object = decltype(object);`

Comment: typeid should give you the polymorphic typ, which you can compare against you known base class type.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is basically how to check whether the *dynamic type* of the object that you have (by pointer or reference to `Base`) is actually `Base`. This is a job for `typeid`:

```
struct Base { /* ... */ };

bool is_actually_base(Base& b) { return typeid(b) == typeid(Base); }
```

If this test returns false, the object must be of a derived class type (or you messed up somewhere and your program has undefined behaviour).

Note that this works only if `Base` contains at least one virtual function (possibly inherited). If that isn't the case, then there is no way to check.